# How do I import various Data Frames from different python file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a python file called 'clean_data.py' which has all the data frames I need, and I want to import them for use in another python file called 'main.py' to use in creating a dashboard.

Is it possible to create a class in my clean_data.py, and if so can someone direct me to an article (which I struggled to find so far) so that I can figure it out?

The aim is to shift from CSV to an API overtime, so I wanted to keep data side wrangling side of things in a different file while the web app components in the main.py file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The code from the clean_data.py is:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os # To access my file directory

print(os.getcwd()) # Let's me know the Current Work Directory

fdi_data = pd.read_csv(r'Data/fdi_data.csv')
fdi_meta = pd.read_csv(r'Data/fdi_metadata.csv')

debt_data = pd.read_csv(r'Data/debt_data.csv')
debt_meta = pd.read_csv(r'Data/debt_metadata.csv')

gdp_percap_data = pd.read_csv(r'Data/gdp_percap_data.csv', header=2)
gdp_percap_meta = pd.read_csv(r'Data/gdp_percap_metadata.csv')

gov_exp_data = pd.read_csv(r'Data/gov_exp_data.csv', header=2)
gov_exp_meta = pd.read_csv(r'Data/gov_exp_metadata.csv')

pop_data = pd.read_csv(r'Data/pop_data.csv', header=2)
pop_meta = pd.read_csv(r'Data/pop_metadata.csv')


"""
'wb' stands for World Bank
"""
def wb_merge_data(data, metadata):
    merge = pd.merge(
        data,
        metadata,
        on = 'Country Code',
        how = 'inner'
    )
    return merge 


fdi_merge = wb_merge_data(fdi_data, fdi_meta) 
debt_merge = wb_merge_data(debt_data, debt_meta)
gdp_percap_merge = wb_merge_data(gdp_percap_data, gdp_percap_meta)
gov_exp_merge = wb_merge_data(gov_exp_data, gov_exp_meta)
pop_merge = wb_merge_data(pop_data, pop_meta)


def wb_drop_data(data):
    drop = data.drop(['Country Code','Indicator Name','Indicator Code','TableName','SpecialNotes','Unnamed: 5'], axis=1)
    return drop


fdi_merge = wb_drop_data(fdi_merge)
debt_merge = wb_drop_data(debt_merge)
gdp_percap_merge = wb_drop_data(gdp_percap_merge)
gov_exp_merge = wb_drop_data(gov_exp_merge)
pop_merge = wb_drop_data(pop_merge)


def wb_mr_data(data, value_name):
    data = data.melt(['Country Name','Region','IncomeGroup']).reset_index()
    data = data.rename(columns={'variable': 'Year', 'value': value_name})
    data = data.drop('index', axis = 1)
    return data


fdi_merge = wb_mr_data(fdi_merge, 'FDI')
debt_merge = wb_mr_data(debt_merge, 'Debt')
gdp_percap_merge = wb_mr_data(gdp_percap_merge, 'GDP per Cap') 
gov_exp_merge = wb_mr_data(gov_exp_merge, 'Gov Expend.')
pop_merge = wb_mr_data(pop_merge, 'Population')


def avg_groupby(data, col_cal, cn=False, ig=False, rg=False):
    if cn == True:
        return data.groupby('Country Name')[col_cal].mean().reset_index()
    elif ig == True:
        return data.groupby('IncomeGroup')[col_cal].mean().reset_index()
    elif rg == True:
        return data.groupby('Region')[col_cal].mean().reset_index()

"""
avg_cn_... For country
avg_ig_... Income Group
avg_rg_... Region
"""
avg_cn_fdi = avg_groupby(fdi_merge, 'FDI', cn=True)
avg_ig_fdi = avg_groupby(fdi_merge, 'FDI', ig=True)
avg_rg_fdi = avg_groupby(fdi_merge, 'FDI', rg=True)

avg_cn_debt = avg_groupby(debt_merge, 'Debt', cn=True)
avg_ig_debt = avg_groupby(debt_merge, 'Debt', ig=True)
avg_rg_debt = avg_groupby(debt_merge, 'Debt', rg=True)

avg_cn_gdp_percap = avg_groupby(gdp_percap_merge, 'GDP per Cap', cn=True)
avg_ig_gdp_percap = avg_groupby(gdp_percap_merge, 'GDP per Cap', ig=True)
avg_rg_gdp_percap = avg_groupby(gdp_percap_merge, 'GDP per Cap', rg=True)

avg_cn_gexp = avg_groupby(gov_exp_merge, 'Gov Expend.', cn=True)
avg_ig_gexp = avg_groupby(gov_exp_merge, 'Gov Expend.', ig=True)
avg_rg_gexp = avg_groupby(gov_exp_merge, 'Gov Expend.', rg=True)

avg_cn_pop = avg_groupby(pop_merge, 'Population', cn=True)
avg_ig_pop = avg_groupby(pop_merge, 'Population', ig=True)
avg_rg_pop = avg_groupby(pop_merge, 'Population', rg=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, every file is a module. So if you want to re-use your code, you can simple import this `module`. For example,

```py
# main.py
import clean_data

print(clean_data.avg_cn_fdi)
```

Maybe you needn't create a class for this

Comment: When I add the below, I get an attribute error

```import clean_data
print(clean_data.avg_cn_fdi)```
AttributeError: module 'clean_data' has no attribute 'avg_cn_fdi'

Comment: forgot to tag you

Comment: @nhamood Could you print `clean_data.fdi_data` or `clean_data.fdi_merge` in `main.py`?

Comment: again I'm getting an **AttributeError** 

Both clean_data.py and main.py are in the same folder, so this was I was thinking the route of creating a class and call them as attributes, or you still think it's not the best way?

Comment: @nhamood You could try, but I don't think that can fix the error. Is the code you provided as same as the real one?

Comment: thank you, I found the error, I had a clean_data.py from a previous edition in my folder, and the most up to date one in a different folder. It's all working now B) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can import the whole python file like you'd import any other locally created files and have access to the DataFrames in them. Here's an example:

I created a file called `temporary.py`:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("temp.csv")
```

And then in a separate file I was able to use `data` like so:

```py
import temporary

print(temporary.data)
```

Or, you could also do:

```py
from temporary import data

print(data)
```

All that being said, I don't believe that this would be the best way to handle your data.

Comment: when I try the following

```import clean_data
print(avg_cn_fdi)```

it gives me a name error as below: 
**bold**NameError: name 'avg_cn_fdi' is not defined**bold**

When i try the following:

```import clean_data
print(clean_data.avg_cn_fdi)```

I get an attriute error:
**bold**AttributeError: module 'clean_data' has no attribute 'avg_cn_fdi'**bold** @charbel-abi-daher